# UITableView realtime reloadData issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data

My app is currency calculator. TableView in ViewController reloads data every time when textfield changes. When [[textField text] length] == 0  tableView should be updated with initial data. Cant share whole code, but it looks like this.

```
ViewController.m

- (void)viewDidLoad {
 [super viewDidLoad];
 array = [Model fromCoreData]; // initial data
}

- (void)textFieldDidChange:(id)textField {
 if([[textField text]length] == 0) {
   array = [Model fromCodeData]; //!
   [tableView reloadData]; // table gets same array that was when textfield length == 1
 }else{
   array = [Model calculate:array withSum:[textField text]]; //return array with calculated data
   [tableView reloadData];
 }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
 //........
 //here [cell setBuy:[[array object atIndex:indexPath]buy]] .......... etc.
 //......
 return cell;
}
```

Problem: when [[textfield text] length] == 0, table gets same array that was when [[textfield text] length] == 1, but not initial (table should take back original data from coredata).

I use MagicalRecord to work with CoreData. NSArray includes entities.
There are no changes in CoreData in real time.
Maybe, somebody faced with same problem? Is there are more proper way?
Sorry for my bad english :)

Comment: what is your problem here?

Comment: I didnt get ur problem xactly

Comment: could not get throughly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this,you'l succeed.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
    NSString *str= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",textField.text,string];
    NSLog(@"---%@",str);
    if([str length]==0){
        array = [Model fromCodeData]; //!
        [tableView reloadData];
    }
    else{
        array = [Model calculate:array withSum:[textField text]];
        [tableView reloadData];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: problem remains same and app does wrong calculations. I think that problem with coredata.

Comment: so may be problem in calculate: method.